# Different combination of '+' and '-'

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many different algebraic quantities can be formed by combining $a,b,c,d \;\text{and}\; e$ with the $'+'$ and $'-'$ signs ,all the letters taken together?

There are four places for the $'+'$ and $'-'$ ,like $\text{a_b_c_d_e}$
How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Must $a$ be always positive?  I.e. is $b+c+d+e-a$ allowed? (which is the same as $-a+b+c+d+e$)

Comment: a is positive always.

Answer (score 2):

For each position there are two possibilities. So in total $2^4=16$.

In case you are allowed to also take $a$ negated there are $5$ places to put a sign so we get $2^5=32$ possibilities.

If there is the additional possibility to drop letters (i.e. also $-a+b+d-e$ is allowed) there are $3$ different scalars for each letter (namely $0$ and $\pm 1$) so we would get $3^5=243$ possibilities in total.

Comment: As suggested in the comment above,if -a is allowed as a valid expression then the total number of such expressions would be 16+1=17,right?

Comment: @Sayantan on the contrary, if $a$ is allowed to be negative, then you can think of it as *five* positions for `+`'s and `-`'s, for $2^5$ instead.

Comment: Yeah,got it,thanks for the help!

Comment: @SayantanBanerjee See my edit.